# SQL query group by using day startdatetime and end datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table `Jobs`:

```
|Id  | StartDateTime       | EndDateTime
+----+---------------------+----------------------
|1   | 2020-10-20 23:00:00 | 2020-10-21 05:00:00
|2   | 2020-10-21 10:00:00 | 2020-10-21 11:00:00
```

Note job id 1 spans October 20 and 21.

I am using the following query

```
SELECT DAY(StartDateTime), COUNT(id)
FROM Job
GROUP BY DAY(StartDateTime)
```

To get the following output. But the problem I am facing is that day 21 is not including job id 1. Since the job spans two days I want to include it in both days 20 and 21.

```
Day | TotalJobs
----+----------
20  | 1
21  | 1
```

I am struggling to get the following expected output:

```
Day | TotalJobs
----+----------
20  | 1
21  | 2
```

Comment: Learn to use a [calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) - as Gordon did. It is so useful for many different situations.

Answer (score 1):

One method is to generate the days that you want and then count overlaps:

```
with days as (
      select convert(date, min(j.startdatetime)) as startd,
             convert(date, max(j.enddatetime)) as endd
      from jobs j
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, startd), endd
      from days
      where startd < endd
     )
select days.startd, count(j.id)
from days left join
     jobs j
     on j.startdatetime < dateadd(day, 1, startd) and
        j.enddatetime >= startd
group by days.startd;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=12d19c87cac6afe3af90f782a0166d0d) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can first group by with same start and end date and then group by for start and end date having different start and end date

```
SELECT a.date, SUM(counts) from (
      SELECT DAY(StartDateTime) as date, COUNT(id) counts
      FROM Table1
      WHERE DAY(StartDateTime) = DAY(EndDateTime)
      GROUP BY StartDateTime
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT DAY(EndDateTime), COUNT(id)
      FROM Table1
      WHERE DAY(StartDateTime) != DAY(EndDateTime)
      GROUP BY EndDateTime
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT DAY(StartDateTime), COUNT(id)
      FROM Table1
      WHERE DAY(StartDateTime) != DAY(EndDateTime)
      GROUP BY StartDateTime) a
GROUP BY a.date
```

Here is SQL Fiddle link
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/701386/1)

Also replace Table1 with Jobs when running over your db context